# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
<script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/boot.js'></script>

<!--upgrade-->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/upgrade.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

without `<script src="node_modules/angular2/upgrade.js"></script>` code works fine.  when i include upgrade.js.it shows " Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in angular2" .How can i overcome from this error.

Answer (score -1):

The `require` function is provided by SystemJS. You need to add it into your `script`:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>
(...)
```

Here is a plunkr describing a working sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/JXLDFBW4A1mi9tyNHoJ3?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @ upgrade.ts:6
angular2-all.umd.js:28560 EXCEPTION: Token must be defined! still error showing

Comment: I added a plunkr with the included scripts. The component in it does nothing but is displayed without any error... Hope it will fix your problem!

Comment: I'm trying `var Rx = require('rx-dom');` in a component, I have included systemJS but gives same error.

Answer (score -3):

Module should be system in tsconfig.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        **"module": "system",**
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noLib": false,
        "declaration": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "jspm_packages",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```