# Angular 2: ReferenceError: require is not defined(…), angular2-polyfills

Tags: typescript, angular

## Edit:

I haven't figure out exactly why it didn't work, but I started from scratch and got a [working version](https://github.com/Ethan826/angular2-express-experiment/tree/workingVersion). It does not appear necessary to put `system.src.js` before the `angular` script tags, *pace* one of the answers below. See both the working version and the Angular 2 [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

---

## Original question:

I am trying to learn Angular 2 and Express. I am generally following [this](http://blog.edenmsg.com/angular2-typescript-gulp-and-expressjs/) guide. I am receiving the following error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined(…) angular2-polyfills.js:1243 
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection @ angular2-polyfills.js:401
(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

Edit: [here](https://github.com/Ethan826/angular2-express-experiment/tree/brokenVersion) is the broken version of the project on GitHub.

My project is structured like so:

```
application
|__client
   |__app
      |__main.ts
      |__main.js
      |__tsconfig.json
   |__typings/ (...)
   |__index.html
   |__typings.json
|__server
   |__server.ts
   |__server.js
   |__tsconfig.json
   |__typings.json
|__node_modules/ (...)
```

The file `server.ts` is like this:

```
import * as express from "express";
let path = require("path");

let app = express();

let PORT = 8080;

app.use("/node_modules", express.static(__dirname + "/../node_modules"));
app.use("/app", express.static(__dirname + "/../client/app"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "client", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log("Listening on port " + PORT)});
```

The `main.ts` file is like this:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";

@Component({
  selector: "app",
  template: "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
})
export class AppComponent {}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The `index.html` file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script> --> 
  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: "register",
          defaultExtension: "js"
        }
      }
    });
    System.import("app/main")
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app></app>
</body>

</html>
```

And the `tsconfig.json` files are both pretty much like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730010/angular2-5-minute-install-bug-require-is-not-defined or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874490/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-in-angular2

Comment: Hmm. I had seen those, but changing the path to `../app.component.js` did not work, as in the first link, and I already have `system.src.js` in my `index.html` file. So I'm not sure those work, unless I misunderstood the answers.

Answer (score 6):

The `angular2-polyfills.js` is a SystemJs bundle, so it needs SystemJs to have already been installed.

This what the message `require is not defined` means, because require is the function that systemjs uses to import modules. To fix this, move the `system.src.js` to the top and make it the first script of the page:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
... other script tags
```

Comment: this does not change anything at my place...same error

Answer (score 0):

I just started with angular 4 today (upgraded from angular2).

Just before my injectable auth class, I added this:

```
// declare var Auth0Lock: any;
declare let require: any;
let Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock').default;
```